# Find how many lines of code written by a developer in Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

Is there a way to report how many lines of code each developer has written in a project or collection? We are using Azure Devops Server 2020.

git fame gives similar results, but more tfvc is used in our projects.

information or extension to learn how to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Lines of code written is a *terrible* metric.

Comment: Hi Buendia, what is the latest status of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to get all lines in your scenario.

And I suppose that you could test the workaround below for your scenario.

Get [commits history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) rest api for your repo commits history.

`GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=6.0`

And then you could use this rest api to get the [differences between the commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#between-commit-ids).

`GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/MyProject/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/diffs/commits?baseVersion=c093714168cdd190c1e171a803e996d685454352&baseVersionType=commit&targetVersion=2f271272a1548da5a6507b4a29f3af943094c6b4&targetVersionType=commit&api-version=6.0`

Or you could start a [feature request ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?) to raise your concern with more developers.

Comment: FYI: In Azure DevOps *Server*, in conjunction with TFVC, that information very well may be in the data warehouse if they have reporting configured. I haven't looked at the reporting data warehouse schema for years, though, and wouldn't recommend trying to derive any meaning from that data if it is available.